# How to fill the svg with a color using css?

Tags: css

i want to fill the complete svg with blue color....currently i can add color to the borders of svg with css fill property. However on clicking svg i want it to completely fill svg blue not only the outline of svg. How can i do this?

Below is what i have tried.

```
<svg onclick={this.on_svg_click}></svg>  

svg {
    padding: 5px;
    > * {
        fill: blue;
}
```

This colors the outline of svg to blue. But how can i fill the entire svg into blue?

Below is the image of how it works with above code.

[image]

But i want something like below picture.

[image]

Could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: from my limited knowledge it is not doable via css since it is about path in svg

Comment: thanks how do  it otherwise.

Comment: sorry, I do not know a specific solution. Once I had similar request and I need to ask my designer team mate to generate a new svg

Comment: The easiest way would be to open your .svg in Illustrator and fill the path using the fill tool.